# LibGDX, Need click event in portable application and in Stage, how?

Tags: java, onclick, libgdx, stage

I am creating a video game with libGDX, for this i need to have 2 click events, one on a stage object, the other on the window.

When i add the stage on my init method with :

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

The event onClick inherited from portable application is disabled...

Is there a solution for my problem ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputMultiplexer(otherInputProcessor, stage));` Swap the order of the two if you want the stage to take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

The solution

```
private InputProcessor inpOne;
```

In the init() Method :

```
inpOne = new InputProcessor() {
            ...
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Hello2");
                return false;
            }
           ...
};
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputMultiplexer(stage, inpOne));
```

The first parameter of newInputMultiplexer is the HighestPriority event !